# Different behavior of PHP’s include/require on Windows and CentOS

Tags: php, windows, centos

These are  code of my PHP applications `myApp.php`and `mypartsA/main.php`.

myApp.php

```
<?php
echo ("##### myApp is starting now !!! </br>");
require_once('/parts/mypartsA/main.php');
?>
```

mypartsA/main.php

```
<?php
echo ("#### mypartsA is required </br>");
?>
```

And `myApp.php` and `mypartsA/main.php` are in following structure.

```
Document_root 
  |
  +--- test
  |     |
  |     +--- myApp.php
  |
  +--- parts
        |
        +--- mypartsA
               |
               +---main.php
```

I’ve used this application on Windows+Apache for a year with no problem but recently I migrate this to CentOS+Apache then I get fatal error related to `include_path`

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(/parts/mypartsA/main.php) 
[<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]
: failed to open stream
: No such file or directory 
in /var/www/html/test/myApp.php on line 12 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]
: Failed opening required (/parts/mypartsA/main.php’
(include_path='.:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/pear/PEAR:/var/www/html') 
in /var/www/html/test/myAPP.php on line 12
```

According to PHP.net if a path is defined the include_path will be ignored.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

I think in my case PHP tries to find `parts` directory from `C:\` or `/` not from `include_path`.

```
require_once(/parts/mypartsA/main.php);
```

Therefore result of `myAPP.php` must be fatal error whether on Windows or on CentOS.

But my application has been working for a year with no error on Windows. PHP can find `parts` directory correctly.

Can sameone try those codes above on Windows and see..

```
##### myApp is starting now !!! 
#### mypartsA is required
```

or get error?

Now,I want to know is why results of same code are different between running on Windows and running on CentOS.

What dirctive in PHP.ini do I have to check ?

I know if I change this code to add absolute path with `$ _SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`.

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']./parts/mypartsA/main.php);
```

It’ll work well. But there are many applications with same style of coding and I don’t want to change all of them.

These are additional information.

include_path values phpinfo() shows on Windows

```
.;C:\PHP;C:\PHP\pear;C:\Apache2.2.22\htdocs
```

include_path values phpinfo() shows on CentOS

```
.:/php/includes:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/pear/PEAR:/var/www/html
```

Comment: linux is case sensitive (windows is not) are you sure that the folder name is `mypartsA` ?

Comment: I'm sure and cheked it is mypartsA.

Comment: confirm that `$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]` actualy point to `/var/www/html/` and that `/var/www/html/parts/mypartsA/main.php` has the execute permissions set right.

Comment: $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]points /var/www/html/.

Comment: And /var/www/html/parts/mypartsA/main.php didn't have permissions. It was rwxr--r--.Then I changed it to rwxr-xr-x.But situation hasn't been changed myApp.php still get Fatal error.

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with the code other then possible permissions issue. a workaround could be to add in the beginning of the file `chroot($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` or `chdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])` and remove the slash

Comment: chroot() and chdir() didn't work.chroot() returned Fatal error as undefined function.Remiving the shalsh is work.But I don't look for the way that chagne the code anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . "/../../parts/mypartsA/main.php";
require_once($path);
```

try with this path

```
$path = "../parts/mypartsA/main.php";
```

the second path should work with document root.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. As I said in question I ‘m looking for the way that I don’t have to change the code.

Comment: I think you havent any way to do this. '/'- filesystems root in linux and php search your files in /some/path but not in /your/webroot/some/path

Comment: @NikitaMelnikov `/` in a php file will point to the root directory of Apache not linux

Comment: Acording to this http://jp2.php.net/manual/ja/function.include.php#94392 article differnce exists. Now I make up my mind to change all source files to Svetlio suggest